# Abstract classes can't be instantiated - Flutter route

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to instantiate a flutter route but it says me that above message. What is the most simple implementation of a Route I can use?

`onPressed: () => Navigator.push({},Route())`

[image]

Comment: The route must be your widget, page, or your custom implemented route. "Route" is an abstract class used as an interface for defining new app routes.
Take a proper look at this https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics.

Comment: Can you include your `Route setting` on  materailApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate to a different route use

```dart
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomePage()));

//Here home page is the name of the class
```

Answer (score -1):

The class 'Scene' is abstract and can't be instantiated.
child: Scene(),

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).